# My simple two column layout breaks when the text gets too long. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

I am building a very simple webpage that has a header, a left-hand navigation box and some content, and a footer. It's using `CSS` to control the layout. It works fine if the text in my content area is short, but if the length of the text gets too long (i.e. in almost all cases) the content area drops below the navigation box rather than sitting nicely up next to the navigation.

The `HTML` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-GB">
    <head>
        <title>Title Goes Here</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />

        <!-- local style sheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/screen.css" media="screen" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <h1>The Header</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="navigation"><!-- Navigation -->
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Navigation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Go</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Here</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- Navigation end -->
            <div id="content"><!-- Main Content Area -->
                <h2>Your Content Goes Here</h2>
                <p>Whatever content you like can go here but if the text is too long it seems to
                break the floating of the content and ends up below the navigation div.
                This is really very annoying and I'd love to know how to fix it.</p>
            </div><!-- Main Content Area end -->
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Some</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Footer</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

and the `CSS` looks like this:

```
body {
    background:#000;
    -webkit-background-size:1920px 1200px /* dimensions of graphic */
    font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;           /* This removes the border around the viewport in old versions of IE */
    min-width:600px;    /* Minimum width of layout - remove line if not required */
                        /* The min-width property does not work in old versions of Internet Explorer */
    font-size:90%;
    width:100%;
}
#header, #wrapper, #footer {
    width:100%;
}
/* Header styles */
#header {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
}

/* main container that wraps the content */
#wrapper {
    position:relative;  /* This fixes the IE7 overflow hidden bug */
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;    /* This chops off any overhanging divs */
    background:#fff;    /* right column background colour */
    margin-top:20px;
    -moz-border-radius:25px;
    border-radius:25px;
}
#content {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:20px;
    padding:0 0 1em 0;
}
#navigation {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background:#000;
    width:150px;
    font-size:.9em;
    margin:40px 0 0 0;
    padding:0 0 1em 0;
    z-index:1002;
}
#navigation li{color:#FFF;background:#000;list-style-type:none;}
#navigation a{text-decoration:none;color:#FFF;display:block;padding:5px 15px;}
#navigation li:hover{}
#navigation li:hover a{color:#FFF;display:block;background:#4f81bd;}
#navigation li:hover ul{display:block;}

#footer {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    font-size:.75em;
    margin-top:30px;
}
#footer p {
    padding:10px;
    margin:0;
}
#footer ul{margin:0;padding:0;}
#footer li, #footer li a{color:#aeaeae;display:inline;padding:0 5px;}
#footer li{list-style-type:none;padding:2px 0;}
#footer li a{font-weight:normal;text-decoration:none;text-transform:none;}
#footer li a:hover{text-decoration:underline;}

h1,h2,h3,h4{color:#4f81bd;}
    h1{font-size:1.6em;}
    h2{font-size:1.3em;}
    h3{font-size:1.2em;}
    h4{font-size:1em;}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: if the width is constant, then fix the width of content div. see this working example http://jsfiddle.net/2U6bz/1/

Comment: Thanks.  That does work if I wish to fix the width of the content, but, alas, I'd like the width of the content area to be flexible.

Comment: Have you tried giving your content and or navigation percentage based max widths (remember to account for padding, margins etc when you work it out)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont float the content div instead give it enough left margin to clear past the navigation div.

Simple two column layout to illustrate here http://jsfiddle.net/DFvyb/

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend trying to use an open source grid system rather than trying to roll your own.

There are many, you could check out this for instance:
https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss/wiki

Comment: Thanks Tom, while that is  interesting, and I will certainly go have a look, it's not the answer to my question and seems all too heavyweight for the very simple page I am constructing.

Answer (score 0):

h2 and p tag should be in div and apply width on div check link below

http://jsfiddle.net/DzQRR/

Answer (score 0):

Set **with** property for **#content** div e.g. 900px